# How do i show output from cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hi i have one problem:

I have fully functioning cookies on my site, but I do not know how to display their content that the user wrote to them

My code is as follows:

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
    } else {
       user = prompt("BlaBlaBla","");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
       }
    }
}
```

And i need to display it into `<h1>` tag there:

```
<h1 class="heading white"><br>Hi

**THERE**

</h1>
<br>
```

The cookie name that i want to show is "username" or "user"

I will be happy for any suggestions for putting cookies in place because I search the internet all day and I do not know the advice

Answer (score 1):

Get the cookie and then just inject it into the html... I would add an ID to the html h1 tag.

```
var user = getCookie("username");

//This won't really work because the id isn't called that
var h1 = document.getElementById("heading white");
h1.innerHTML = user;
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i insert the cookie into the h1 tag? I try insert it into h1 using ID but not works. Can i use "output" or something other?